# Spark - error when selecting a column from a struct in a nested array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, struct, pyspark, nested

=========== UPDATED ========

I added some more details in my JSON (the struct_c and the array_d) to make it clearer on where I got the exception.

============================

Good day,

I have a Spark DataFrame with a nested array of type struct. I want to select a column from that struct, but got the error message: "*org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`home`.`array_a`.`array_b`['a']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''a'' is of string type*".

Here is my data:

```
{
  "home": {
    "a_number": 5,
    "a_string": "six",
    "array_a": [
      {
        "array_b": [{"a": "1", "b": 2}],
        "struct_c": {"a": 1.1, "b": 1.3},
        "array_d": ["a", "b", "c"]
      },
      {
        "array_b": [{"a": "3", "b": 4}],
        "struct_c": {"a": 1.5, "b": 1.6},
        "array_d": ["x", "y", "z"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my data schema:

```
mydf1 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("myJson.json")
mydf1.printSchema()

root
 |-- home: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a_number: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a_string: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- array_a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- array_b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- array_d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- struct_c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- b: double (nullable = true)
```

When I select data from either the struct_c or the array_d (array of strings) inside that array_a, there was no issue.

```
mydf1.select("home.array_a.array_d").show(10, False)

+----------------------+
|array_d               |
+----------------------+
|[[a, b, c], [x, y, z]]|
+----------------------+

mydf1.select(col("home.array_a.struct_c.a").alias("struct_field_inside_arrayA")).show(10, False)

+--------------------------+
|struct_field_inside_arrayA|
+--------------------------+
|[1.1, 1.5]                |
+--------------------------+
```

And here is where it failed:

```
mydf1.select("home.array_a.array_b.a").printSchema()
mydf1.select("home.array_a.array_b.a").show()
```

What I expect is a two-dimension array of string (*[["1", "3"]] is my sample JSON*)

Could you please help on why it failed?

Thanks for your help.

> Fail to execute line 4:
>   mydf1.select("home.array_a.array_b.a").printSchema() Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
>   in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
>   328, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o15300.select. :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '`home`.`array_a`.`array_b`['a']' due to data type mismatch: argument
>   2 requires integral type, however, ''a'' is of string type.;; 'Project
>   [home#18213.array_a.array_b[a] AS a#18217]
>   +- Relation[home#18213] json
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:121)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3407)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1335)  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor348.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5197917387349583174.py", line 380, in 
>       exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)   File "", line 4, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
>   1320, in select
>       jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69,
>   in deco
>       raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve
>   '`home`.`array_a`.`array_b`['a']' due to data type mismatch: argument
>   2 requires integral type, however, ''a'' is of string
>   type.;;\n'Project [home#18213.array_a.array_b[a] AS a#18217]\n+-
>   Relation[home#18213] json\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have no problem with the **element_at()** function, I supposed you are using the **spark 2.4+**, then you can try Spark SQL built-in functions: **transform** [[1]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform)[[2]](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html#) + **flatten**:

```
>>> mydf1.selectExpr('flatten(transform(home.array_a.array_b, x -> x.a)) as array_field_inside_array').show()
+------------------------+
|array_field_inside_array|
+------------------------+
|                  [1, 3]|
+------------------------+
```

Where we use **transform()** function to retrieve only the values of field `a` of each array element of `home.array_a.array_b` and transform them to the array `[[1], [3]]`. then flatten that array into `[1, 3]`. If you need the result to be `[[1, 3]]`, then just add array() function

```
array(flatten(transform(home.array_a.array_b, x -> x.a)))
```

Comment: Thank you @jxc. It works. To have that [[1, 3]] I just only need to remove that "flatten". Does it make any difference between having array(flatten(transform())) and just transform()?

And I couldn't find transform()'s equivalent in PySpark. Is it in the form of some other name?
Thanks

Comment: @Averell, with `transform()` only, we get `[[1], [3]]` which I think is not what you are looking for? that's why I added flatten() function. **transform()** is one of the Spark SQL buildin functions (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/sql/index.html). With pyspark dataframes, we can always use `df.selectExpr()` or `spark.sql.functions.expr()` to run these SQL functions :), you can google `spark sql higher order functions` for some more examples of functions related to the array operations.

Answer (score 4):

Since `array_a` and `array_b` are array type you cannot select its element directly

You need to explode them as below or you can get by Index

```
mydf1.withColumn("array_a", explode($"home.array_a"))
  .withColumn("array_b", explode($"array_a.array_b"))
  .select("array_b.a").show(false)
```

This will gice you

```
+---+
|a  |
+---+
|1  |
|3  |
+---+
```

Comment: Thank you Shankar.
However, "Since array_a and array_b are array type you cannot select its element directly" <<< this is not true, as in my original post, it is possible to select "home.array_a.another_number".

I don't want to use explode though, as I will end up having too many records with duplicated value on other columns. And in the subsequent aggregations, there's a the need to do groupBy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can select by this:

```
spark.sql("SELECT home.array_a.array_b[0].a FROM <table>")
```

Comment: Thank you Lamanus. But that would only give the first element of the array array_b.

Comment: Then add more cols as you wish.

Comment: But I need the struct field "a" from ALL elements in array_b, not all struct fields from the 1st element in array_b.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it failed because you are trying to print the schema of a value not a column.

So if you remove "a" from the select statement then you can print the desired schema.

```
scala> dataDF.select("home.array_a.array_b").printSchema
root
 |-- array_b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

If you want value from the array ( array_b ), you need to give the index.

```
scala> dataDF.select(element_at(col("home.array_a.array_b"),1)).show
+-----------------------------------+
|element_at(home.array_a.array_b, 1)|
+-----------------------------------+
|                           [[1, 2]]|
+-----------------------------------+
```

Can you also give the expected dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. But that would only give the first element of array_b, which is a struct of 2 struct-fields "a" and "b".


What I need is the struct field "a" from ALL elements in array_b (which should be [["1", "3"]] in my sample json.

Comment: your output is a dataframe with each record to be an array of structs/tuples [(1, 2)]. My expected. While I need a dataframe with each record to be an array of array of string [["1", "3"]].