# Column attributes of type STRUCT cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have this sql statement

```
Select distinct _data.attributes from rd-bigdata-lake-prd.lake_gcs.xyz
```

and I get this error

```
400 Column attributes of type STRUCT cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT
```

The value of _data.attributes is

```
{"url":"/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Message/123456789","type":"Message"}
```

How to change the sql statement, that the field _data.attributes is readable with select distinct?
I tried to cast _data.attributes to string. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285628/spark-error-when-selecting-a-column-from-a-struct-in-a-nested-array answer your question? I'm presuming you need to explode and flatten your `struct` schema.

Comment: While working on adding a demo to my answer I realized that I don't get any error for select distinct. Can you supply a data sample and code so we can try and reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the struct to string using [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_json)

```
select distinct 
       to_json(_data.attributes)

from   rd-bigdata-lake-prd.lake_gcs.xyz
```